# How to lauch prorams in Apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I have a “myprogram.py” and my “myprogram.scala” that I need to run on my spark machine. How Can I upload and launch them?

I have been using shell to do my transformation and calling actions, but now I want to launch a complete program on spark machine instead of entering single commands every time. Also I believe that will make it easy for me to make changes to my program instead of starting to enter commands in shell.

I did standalone installation in Ubuntu 14.04, on single machine, not a cluster, used spark 1.4.1.

I went through spark docs online, but I only find instruction on how to do that on cluster. Please help me on that.

Thank you.

Comment: [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) has an example how to submit in a local mode.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation to do this (as commented above) is available here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

However, the code you need is here:

```
# Run application locally on 8 cores
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master local[8] \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  100
```

You'll need to compile the scala file using sbt (documentation here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html)

Here's some information on the build.sbt file you'll need in order to grab the right dependencies: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Once the scala file is compiled, you'll send the resulting jar using the above submit command.

Answer (score 0):

Put it simply:

1. In Linux terminal, cd to the directory that spark is unpacked/installed
   Note, this folder normally contains subfolders like “bin”, “conf”, “lib”,  “logs” and so on.
2. To run the Python program locally with simple/default settings, type command

   ./bin/spark-submit --master local[*] myprogram.py

More complete descriptions are [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) like zero323 and ApolloFortyNine described.